# Style DataTrigger Setter in Button Content is invalid

Tags: wpf

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="" x:Name="input"/>
    <Button Content="DataTrigger Before">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=input, Path=Text}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Changed"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Style DataTrigger Setter in Button Content is invalid

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your **DataTrigger** is not change the value of the `Content` property because you set it inside the **Button** declaration. So, once setted, it will never changed. To allow changing, you have to set the value inside the **Style**.

This will works (I've tried):

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="input"/>
    <Button>
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="DataTrigger Before"></Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=input, Path=Text}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Changed"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```