# Bind button content inside Datagrid to column value If condition is true

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i have `DataGrid` in which i have several columns .i also have one `Button` inside `DataGrid` . now when `DataGrid` loads i want to change button content.i want to check status of "status column" .then according to that i want to change content of button inside `DataGrid`. Here is what i want to achieve

**E.g**

```
if(Status="Accepted"){
closeorderbtn.content="Close Order"
}

else{
closeorderbtn.content="Open Order"
}
```

**Xaml file**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" SelectionMode="Single" MouseLeftButtonUp="dataGrid_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseDoubleClick="dataGrid_MouseDoubleClick" Background="WhiteSmoke" RowBackground="White" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ColumnWidth="*" Height="534" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1174" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray" GridLinesVisibility="All" Margin="4,6,0,0">
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total_Quantity" Binding="{Binding Total_Quantity}" FontFamily="B Nazanin" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rate" Binding="{Binding RatePerTon, StringFormat=\{0:n0\}}" FontFamily="B Nazanin" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Discount" Binding="{Binding Discount}" FontFamily="B Nazanin" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Final_" Binding="{Binding Final_Cost,StringFormat=\{0:n0\}}" FontFamily="B Nazanin" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Payment_" Binding="{Binding Payment_Mode}" FontFamily="B Nazanin" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="status" Binding="{Binding Status}" FontFamily="B Nazanin" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="80" >

            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button x:Name="closeorderbtn" Content=""   Click="CloseOrder" Background="#FF5890BF" Foreground="#FFBFBCBC"   />


                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

**CS**

```
IQueryable<Order> result;

result = (from s in ManagerClass.oSqlData.Orders select s);

dataGrid.ItemsSource = result;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Style DataTrigger Setter in Button Content is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060932/style-datatrigger-setter-in-button-content-is-invalid)

Comment: it shows how to change content of button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Style` with a `DataTrigger`:

```
<Button x:Name="closeorderbtn" Content="" Click="CloseOrder" Background="#FF5890BF" Foreground="#FFBFBCBC">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Open Order" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Accepted">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Close Order" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```